# How to handle AskTimeoutException in play controller

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, future, akka-remote-actor

Hi I want to wrap AskTimeOutException and send proper message ....

```
  class Application @Inject()(system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {
  def index = Action { Ok("Welcome")}
  val ref: ActorSelection = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://NLPSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/nlp")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  def nlp(query: String) = Action.async {
      val fut: Future[NLPResponse] = (ref ? NLPRequest(query)).mapTo[NLPResponse]
      fut map {
        case e: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException => InternalServerError("NLP engine is down please try after some time")
        case res: NLPResponse => Ok(res.response)
      }
  }
}
```

Please suggest me proper way to handle it..

Answer (score 2):

Future errors should be handle using the [recover combinator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]):

```
fut map {
  case res: NLPResponse => Ok(res.response)
} recover {
  case _: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException => InternalServerError("NLP engine is down please try after some time")
  case e => InternalServerError("Other error: " + e.getMessage)
}
```